Диалоговое окно, когда внесены поправки в форму, пользователь уходит со страницы не сохраняя
document.querySelector('.forma [type=submit]').onclick = _ => (clik = true);
window.onbeforeunload = e => {
   if(typeof clik != 'boolean') 
       return (e.returnValue = 'Dialog text here')
};

Смущает, что необходимо вешать еще один слушатель на форму.
Возможно для данной задачи выполнить проще? Хотя бы меньше когда, а если один слушатель будет вообще супер...
Если есть клик по форме, расцениваю это как пользователь внес поправки в статью и если форма не отправлена, а страница обновляется. Напоминаю пользователю, что внесенные поправки не будут сохранены.

Не ясно в чём вопрос. В том что смущает несколько слушателей на одном элементе? Ну и что. Задачу нужную выполняет?  Этого достаточно. .... А слушателей на элементе может быть и десяток

.onclick Есть ли варианты, обойтись без данного собы тия. Только при помощи onbeforeunload, определить что в форме внесены поправки, прежде чем пользователь закроет страницу, либо обновить, уйдет, не сохранив.

При загрузке страницы складируются данные в хранилище (например в переменную), при onbeforeunload делается тоже самое и потом сравниваюттся показатели. Если есть diff - значит были изменения. Расхождение обычно можно получить через сравнение двух объектов переводя их в JSON.stringify
